# I am trying to implement a code using 'extern' keyword, IDE: VS Code (using code runner...)

Tags: c, extern

**extrn.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int var;

int main()
{
    printf("%d", var);
    return 0;
}
```

**var.c**

```
int var = 5;
```

I go to file extrn.c and I run the code and I get this:

> undefined reference to `var'

and this is what my output is looking like:

###### [Running] cd "/home/buff/Documents/Coding/C/C_programming_NESO/" && gcc extrn.c -o extrn && "/home/buff/Documents/Coding/C/C_programming_NESO/"

###### /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccoKgi02.o: in function `main':

###### extrn.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `var'

###### collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

###### [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.093 seconds

Comment: How exactly are you trying to build those two files into an executable? Which commandline do you try? Makefile? Ide config?

Comment: @Yunnosch Its a bit clear ```I go to 1st file and I run the code and I get this:```

Comment: @Yunnosch According to me OP is new, he was using VSCODE with code runner extension, which only compiled the `extrn.c` file.

Comment: @Darth-CodeX According to me your guesses are 1/3 probable 2/3 daring. I prefer to not assume for an answer.

Comment: @Yunnosch Now let the OP decide

Comment: ok, so I AM using vs code and code runner... rest I've pasted the whole output window there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile your both `C` files together to fix this `undefined reference` error.

###### For GCC

```sh
gcc extrn.c var.c -o main
```

###### For clang

```sh
clang extrn.c var.c -o main
```

Comment: not working... ...

Comment: @Shrayansh You are just running `gcc extrn.c -o extrn` run instead `gcc extrn.c var.c -o main`. ***Accept my answer if it worked***

Comment: buff@d605:/media/buff/92AA5210AA51F0E9/Documents/Coding/C/C_programming_NESO$ gcc extern.c var.c -o main
gcc: error: extern.c: No such file or directory

Comment: @Shrayansh Use `cd` command and go into that directory in which both files are stored.

Comment: buff@d605:~/Documents/Coding/C/C_programming_NESO$ pwd
/home/buff/Documents/Coding/C/C_programming_NESO
buff@d605:~/Documents/Coding/C/C_programming_NESO$ gcc extern.c var.c -o main
gcc: error: extern.c: No such file or directory
Brother, thank you for your effort, it is not much of an issue, leave it, and thanks again.